# Remove maximize, minimize, close button from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdesktoppane

In JDesktopPane, i have included a JPanel with tree view listing some devices. I dont need those resizable and close options in that panel show in the figure. (Maximize, Minimize, Close). I tried many ways, but not able to hide those functions. Any ideas.

[image]

Comment: [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) has `setMaximizable()`, `setIconifiable()` and `setClosable()`.

Comment: Is that a [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)? If so, use `setIconifiable(false)` and `setMaximizable(false)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component you actually need to be dealing with is the [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) which contains the JPanel you mentioned above. This should have a number of functions to enable/disable the actions associated with the min/max/close buttons (E.g.: `setMaximizable(bool enabled)` ).

I do not know if this would hide the buttons or merely disable them, so you may have to use some variant of the trick mentioned by R.J - manually removing the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
setMaximizable(false), 
setMinimizabel(false), 
setClosable(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the minimize, maximize and close buttons from a swing component like this:-

```
public void removeMinMaxClose(Component comp) {
    if (comp instanceof AbstractButton) {
        comp.getParent().remove(comp);
    }
    if (comp instanceof Container) {
        Component[] comps = ((Container) comp).getComponents();
        for (int x = 0, y = comps.length; x < y; x++) {
            removeMinMaxClose(comps[x]);
        }
    }
}
```